User temp folder is 103GB. Is it safe to delete?
On a Surface Book 2 it takes forever to get to the login screen after a reboot with 'waiting for ProfSvc' - I noticed that the file at Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp is 103GB which is quite a chunk for a 1TB drive that has 553GB free!
Is it normal for this directory to be so large? 632,268 files in 182,521 directories!
Is it safe to just delete this?
UPDATE
I did try storage sense - it showed the temp files, just under apps...

Next,  I selected to remove 96GB...

It ran for about a minute - when I checked again nothing had changed, zilch - still the same. So, I guess that is one solution that doesn't work :-(
FURTHER UPDATE - AND A WORD OF CAUTION
I took the plunge and deleted the files - the main culprit appears to be VS2022 installer files that are not being cleaned up

Then I had a problem with Notes not opening emails and throwing 'Notes Error: File does not exist (CalendarProfile)' Mmmmm too much of a coincidence. Shut down notes and restarted - it failed with 'unable to find files in' yeah, you guessed it - in their infinite wisdom IBM stuck critical files in the user temp directory.
Luckily, I had a full backup and was able to mount that as a drive and copy the relevant directory and files back - Notes then started and once again I have email, but I am down a good chunk of brandy (yeah, the drink not the stripper).
So, if you are going down the route of deleting everything make sure you have a backup - there are utilities that can recover data if it's not been overwritten (saved me when my ex deleted a load of files and emptied the trash) but backups are critical.

"Nothing had changed" - do you mean by this that it didn't sort out your problem with slow reboot, or do you mean that it didn't even delete any files? If disk cleanup says that it's going to delete 96GB of files and then doesn't actually delete anything, then I'd be a bit surprised and curious to know just how bad the application is that's creating them and preventing them being deleted. If deleting temp files fails to speed up reboot then I'm not really surprised at all, since there's a lot of reasons boot could be slow.

Didn't delete any files

Hmm. Yeah, take the answers that say to delete files manually, I suppose. I rarely bother to delete temp files, but when I do I usually find specific things that are (a) big, (b) old, (c) I have some idea what app it's from. Between (b) and (c) hopefully it's obvious that nothing could possibly still be using it, and (a) stops you wasting time on trivia.

It's a little annoying that 'temp' files are taking almost as much space as applications - especially when you consider that I use this as a development machine and have VS installed, a local version of IIS running, a database server with some 60 databases loaded and Notes client that has archived emails from over 20 years and current emails of 167,844 documents. I'm actually quite impressed that a laptop can cope with all that and only fall apart after six months without rebooting

Don't! The way my employer's IT has my dev laptop set up, I'm lucky to go 2 weeks without rebooting. For me, 103GB in 6 months feels like quite a lot, and 600k files + 200k folders is past the point where Windows 11 can sometimes struggle when you actually act on those files. Personally I wouldn't spend a lot of time on it, but I'd try to work out specifically which app is creating them and why, before deleting them.

Regarding the auto delete through the cleanup app, it may have issued a command but then remove the files manually in a separate thread. When I answered this question and checked my own system, I had 98 gig of temp that I manually deleted. There are an extreme amount of small files, and those take a lot to delete. The window itself was deleting for almost 25 minutes and this is on my fast SSD too, but after that, it would stall at 100% with just a few seconds remaining. I closed the window but noticed explorer had still lots of CPU usage. This remained for several hours.

Lotus Notes? Is this a company-owned computer?

@music2myear - Lotus > IBM > HCL - The answer to company-owned is both yes and no. No in the sense that I don't work for a mega corporation and yes in that it's used for my work.

The size of the corp is irrelevant. The question is whether the computer and/or the software BELONGS to a corp you are working for. This is relevant because what a corp does on that computer may differ from normal computer operations, you are likely to have less than admin permissions, and you may be personally governed by some employment contract that stipulates support requirements for the system. All these are very relevant to HOW your problem may be fixed.

@music2myear - The computer belongs to the corp and the corp belongs to me.

Got it. Thanks for clarifying.

I've seen temp folders grow in size like this. Often the computers in question don't have as much free storage space, so I notice it sooner. Like when there is 50GB used in the temp folder.
I have not figured out why this can happen, but it does.
In any case, you can simply go to that folder, Select all, Delete and confirm. This will ask if you want to move all files in that folder to the recycle bin. Make sure you are indeed in the temp folder, then hit yes.
Normally I would say, just shift-delete it, but it appears that IBM stores sensitive userdata in the temp folder.
It will try to delete all files, but it will fail on a few files that are currently in use. This is normal. Skip all those files and continue.
Test that everything still works, reboot if you can to make extra sure, if all still works, delete the files from the recycle bin.
They will eventually be deleted, either automatically or in the future by you if you do it again.
I seldomly have to do this. Maybe once a year or so, or less, and it never has caused an issue.
This actually used to be an issue back in the Windows XP days and earlier.

I suspect these files get 'stranded' when Windows throws the toys around and crashes unexpectedly - I know we write desktop apps that save setting when they are closed, but on the rare occasion that it crashes that doesn't, of course, happen. Currently running a backup, so when that is done will have a go at deleting - thanks for taking the time to reply :-)

Windows 10 and 11 should have this option or better said ability to do it manually, try searching "Storage sense" from start menu and turn it on. Enter its options to finetune how long to keep temp files.

@Danijel - what if I have directories that I created called 'temp?'

@gchq that does not matter how you call them or if you have 1000's of "temp" folders allover your drive(s), it matters what is written for "default" TEMP path in your OS "Environment Variables" for both user(by default:%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp) and os(by default:%SystemRoot%\TEMP).

@gchq It’s usually the apps themselves not handling temp files well. Windows doesn’t provide a sane API for automatically tying the lifetime of a temporary file to the process that created it (this is trivial to do on UNIX-like systems like macOS or Linux), so the application itself has to make a point to clean up it’s own temporary files, and quite a few simply don’t do so.

Actually I wonder: If disk is becoming full, normally Windows suggests to remove temporary files. Also, there is a tool to delete temporary files. In German Windows it's called "System > Speicher > Temporäre Dateien"

@U.Windle - The problem is not that the disk is full, it is that logging in takes forever and I suspect that is because the user temp directory is so large. Could be wrong. Either way I ran Storage Sense and posted the result in an update to the original post.

@gchq - No. Not because current day Windows versions really don't tend to crash (anecdotal but I haven't seen a BSOD in probably a decade or so) but because temp usage is the responsibility of the applications. Having said that, Disk Cleanup does clean the temp folder as well, and it should be used regularly, especially in its "system files" mode because upgrade leftovers can amount to many gigabytes, unnecessarily. So it's not really a question of why Windows doesn't do it because it does if you use the proper tool. The question is more like why people don't use the tool...

@Gábor - No BSOD for a decade? Sheesh I need a bottle of brandy after each Patch Tuesday with our servers - knowing one of them is going to throw the toys around and BSOD.

Servers, OK, you win. I never ever succumbed to the bad idea of using Windows for servers, only for desktop. And even there, I never ever used 95/98, Vista or 8. I went NT in the beginning and stayed there until everybody caught up with it. :-)

@Gábor - Odd I did the same. In fact, used Netware for servers until Lotus (as it was then before IBM bought them) saw the writing on the wall and dropped support for that platform. Still didn't understand why MS DOS beat OS2 which was far better, but having the NSA fund the operation for a back door might have helped. There again I bought a Betamax video recorder, a Windows phone (that I still use) and an Essential phone (that I also still use)

As a word of caution, I have updated the original question - make sure you have a backup or the proverbial could hit the fan - some developers (IBM) actually put critical files in the temp directory!

I've edited the answer so it better suits this discovery.

@LPChip - Noticed the edits - but 'if all still works, delete the files from the recycle bin.' I suspect that the volume might be too large for that utility and it will throw a warning to that effect. Either copy to another drive or make a current backup. Not sure WHY there is a limit as it's only changing a flag. So far no other apps have kicked off, and that - as Martha would say - is a good thing :-)

@gchq no, you are moving files from one location on that drive to another on that same drive. From %temp% to c:$RECYCLE.BIN. There's no quota for the recycle bin. The only thing that could happen is that if you leave the files in the recycle bin for too long, the automatic maintenance task will start removing some of those files from the recycle bin.

@LPChip, there actually is. RMB your Recycle bin and go to properties. In most cases I think "default" is around 5% of total disk(each disk shows own 5%) size.

I'd suggest to "delete it normally" (i.e. its moved to trash), then reboot and see if everything is still working normally.
If so, then delete the file from trash; otherwise recover it from trash.

That's a great idea, as long the trash can can actually handle that much data!

It's not one file, it's thousands of them - 632k to be exact.

@security_paranoid The trash is just a folder on disk. But it's actually not required, clearing "temp" is always safe, by definition.

@gchq Next time around you see something like this, peek into the folder and the names might reveal which program was the culprit. Although nothing stops a program from doing so, it's not really acceptable behavior to litter that much without removing it later. What doesn't mean you can always do something about it, of course, except for complaining at the developer. As said above, it's very unlikely to be Windows itself.

And while there's no accounting for what applications decide actually to do, but if they're behaving as applications should and usually do, then no temp file needs to be retained across a reboot. If an application needs a file to stick around, it should save it somewhere else (and there are designated places for that, in AppData). So when Gábor says, "always safe, by definition", I think that's what is meant.

"always safe, by definition": Hope the programmers know also ;-)

@U.Windl They do. No program puts something in the temp folder accidentally. (There are much easier folders to put things in accidentally.)

@Gábor
'peek into the folder and the names might reveal which program was the culprit.' - I have updated the question - the bulk appear for be Visual Studio installer files, so MS back in the crosshairs I guess.

@gchq True, both IDEs and installers are among the worst offenders. However, I stumbled upon this recently, rather accidentally. Do you happen to know this? I did the same, created a new drive for all my dev files (including the various SDKs and repositories like Nuget, NodeJS, Pub.dev, etc) to a ReFS drive on a SSD and it really helped with both speed and cleanliness. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-drive/
